# Possibility of installing a certificate from an app

Tags: ios, keychain, client-certificates

Is it possible to install a `certificate` from an app in the keychain?

I didn't find anything like that. The only one I could find is to store only a string to the `keychain` like a password or something.

Comment: Install a certificate *where*?

Comment: @Droppy Sry, edited my post. In the keychain

Answer (score 0):

No Dude, you can not do that in iOS. Key chain technology is totally different in MacOSX and iOS. In ios Keychain can be seen as encrypted store with Dictionary data structure. This page covers the keychain in detail [basic Keychain Services functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html)

Comment: At your linked URL there is following written "In iOS Keychain Services, certificates, keys, and identities are stored and retrieved in exactly the same way as passwords, except that they have different attributes."! Doesn't it mean I can import my certificate in the keychain?